# why when re-assigning pointer to char for 1D array shows error but 2D array works fine?

Tags: c++

Iam totally confused with 1d and 2d array by seeing this problem.

```
Example:


   char *ar[3] = { 'a', 'b' };
    ar[1] = 'f';     // shows error that i could not assign
    char *games[3] = {
        "roadrash",
        "nfs",
        "angrybirds"
    };
    games[0] = "hitman";   // works fine
```

Comment: `char *ar[3] = { 'a', 'b' };` is not allowed in C++; you should get an error message and if you don't then I would strongly recommend changing your compiler settings until you see an error message. This will save you from wasting time dealing with consequences of trying to run erroneous code .

Comment: Maybe you meant `char ar[3]` instead (in which case you would not get an error for the assignment following)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no two-dimensional arrays in your code. it's one-dimensional arrays of pointers to `char*`.

All lines of that code are erroneous

```
char *ar[3] = { 'a', 'b' };
```

`char*` and `const char` are not compatible types. If you meant to declare an array of 3 characters it would be

```
char ar[3] = { 'a', 'b' };
ar[1] = 'f';   // ar is now "af\0"
```

you can't initialize  non-const `char*` with string literal. Array `games` of pointers at `char`

```
char *games[3] = {
```

should be

```
const char *games[3] = {
```

to be correct. If pointee's type isn't `const char`, then initialization and following assignment

```
games[0] = "hitman";
```

are incorrect because you cannot assign strings to a pointer at `char` only to pointers at `const char`. String literals represent constant buffers and in that case it's the pointer that changes value and points to a different string preallocated by compiler. If you need mutable strings, you need to have a buffer allocated large enough for copying a string into it, e.g.

```
char *  games[3];
const char*  hitman = "hitman";
games[0] = new char[strlen(hitman)+1];
strcpy(games[0], hitman);
```

To be frank it's a crap code if we talk about standard C++. You're strongly recommended to use  standard string component to manipulate strings.

```
// #include <string> assumed
// does all allocation inside of constructor
std::string  games[3] = {
    "roadrash",
    "nfs",
    "angrybirds"
};
// reallocated and copies storage as per to operator=
games[0] = "hitman";
```

Comment: This answer started off OK, but `games[0] = "hitman;"` is correct, after the change to `const char *`. `games[0]` is a pointer and it can be made to point to the const char array `"hitman"` . There is no need to copy a string, let alone manually allocate memory. Also your suggested code contains a buffer overflow  (which could have been avoided by not doing that at all).

Comment: Thank you all for your answer.....i am still not clear how pointer to char of 1D and 2D array behavious like this..but this  does not show any error i.e char *ar[3] = { "a", "b" };
 ar[1] = "f";

Comment: @M.M yeah, because I didn't wrote like that since 90s and I'm at war with my phone, my bad :P

Comment: @Rahul, there is no 2D arrays in your code. it's 1D arrays of pointers to char*. Which can point to some character sequences. 2D array would have two indexes, e.g. `char ar[10][3]`; and is monotonous storage of 30 characters. char *ar[3]; got storage for three pointers, characters are stored somewhere else.